# How I can return to default after run sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/?

Tags: macos, terminal, console

How I can return to default after run

> sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/

I know now that was a mistake, How I can return to the default config?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a [BSD.usr.dist](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/etc/mtree/BSD.usr.dist) for macOS, or probably they share the same as [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?mtree(8)), from there you could check the default permissions.

Normally to fix up the directory permissions, [mtree](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mtree.8.html) could be used, for example:

```
# cd /usr
# mtree -U -f /etc/mtree/BSD.usr.dist
```

The "problem" is that in macOS there is no `/etc/mtree` directory, but by checking the `BSD.usr.dist` this can be found:

```
/set type=dir uname=root gname=wheel mode=0755
```

so you could use:

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel /usr/local
```